# Change route when React.js component changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not quite sure what would be the best way to handle a particular scenario.

With 2 components rendered on the **same** page, links in one component will control the data displayed in the other component.

I am using the Flux pattern, so I typically would propagate this through, but my goals are:

- **reflect the change in the url /path**
- **no actually navigate away or cause transition**

**One of my constraints is**: the component with the links is a 3rd-party library that renders the links.  But I have control ove the URL's.

I am not sure if it is possible to both:

1. **use the Flux pattern for this scenario**
2. **And (with react-router) reflect the selection in the URL**

e.g.

/some/url/1

[comp1] -> link clicked -> [comp2] -> displayed data changed

path becomes ->  /some/url/2

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the 3rd party component you are using?

Comment: the displayed URL is a part of the view, i don't see any problems with doing both.

Comment: The 3rd party lib is Vis.js timeline.